# Need help in choosing Flash size in a microcontroller

Tags: flash, msp, ram

I need to decide upon selecting Flash size and RAM for a project. The micro controller I prefer to use is TI MSP430 series. Because of its low power consumption and value line series cost. However I'm a complete newbie to deciding on requirements gathering. Most of my programming experience is on Desktop based systems where generally program size, RAM and processor speed isn't much of a concern for common algorithmic tasks.

I have the following questions:

1. Are there any guidelines or standard practices regarding deciding the RAM and Flash size for a micro controller?
2. How many lines of code (C) translate to what amount of Flash size on the MCU?
3. Is assembly language the only way out if the Flash size needs to kept at a minimum?

Regarding General selection of a Micro controller for a project, how do the professionals in this field go about on deciding the most appropriate micro controller for the task? What resources to they search? What guidelines to they follow?

Answer (score 7):

The answers for all of your questions will depend of what you wanna do.

As you said, you are a newbie, so I suggest you use the biggest microcontroller and just try to do the project. After this you can visualize how much code you use and then scale it according to what was used.

Comment: Agreed. Start with something big, and then if necessary pare down to the smallest part that meets your final requirements.

Comment: "Biggest" needs to be qualified with "In the series you're targetting".  Find the peripherals you need, and the speed class you need, choose an architecture/family, and then develop with the largest processor in that family.  Don't start out with something with 512kB of Flash and 64kB of RAM because it's the biggest microcontroller you can find; narrow it down to Cortex-M3 vs. AVR vs. PIC18 vs. MSP430 (for example) before you start worrying about size.  I suspect that Daniel expected this, but just thought it needed to be stated somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

As far as the msp430, it is a good architecture, pretty good tools out there mspgcc and mspgcc4 and llvm for that matter.  binutils without patching.  You can get a launchpad for under $5 at that price buy a few (eventually you will brick something or short it out and melt it down, have a spare, esp at this price)...

Download the tools, they are all free, write a few lines of code, learn how to link it, see how big the binary gets, get a feel for embedded, lines of code to rom size, etc.

How do pros do it.  Just about every way you can imagine:

Some companies the mandate comes down from on high and there is nothing you can do about it other than quit.  And you may never know why that platform was chosen.

Sometimes the contractor/favorite customer dictates the platform, sometimes you can educate/negotiate, sometimes not.

Some folks just have a favorite, fear of the unknown, whatever.  Same reason why some folks buy only one brand of car, cause my dad did and his dad did before that, and that could be the whole reason.

Some folks focus on the tools.  Here again you have brand loyal folks, limiting themselves to their favorite compiler company and whatever targets they support, or favorite open source tool and what that supports.  Favorite embedded operating system and limit to the targets that supports.

In some cases it is about tools but in a different way, over time you may have invested a lot of money in annual support contracts with a vendor (say arm or xilinx or motorola for example) and it could be that you have liked their support and dont want to change or the devil you know is better than the devil you dont.  Or it could be that because the other 5 active projects in the company use this thing and we already have a support contract and will continue to pay for that year after year you must choose one of those vendors solutions.

Sometimes it is about saving the millipennies.  This part is 1.5% cheaper than that part, make it work with this part, dont care about the NRE, think about the manufacturing savings in volume.

Sometimes it is about the negatives.  One vendor may have screwed your company in one way or another.  Failure to meet the advertised supply of parts causing delays or cancellation of your products.  Bait and switch scams (the $50,000 fee for the software did not include the $1200 fee for the dongle required to unlock the license, that is an extra cost item.  Oh and that was per user for the floating license).  Once you sign the NDA to see the programmers reference manual or reference design guide you find out how dreadful their engineering is and you may choose to blacklist all of their products for life.  Past history with horrible tech support.  Any number of reasons may cause you to never allow their sales folks in the front door, or keep you from ever looking at their website again.

Sometimes it has to do with performance, interfaces, etc.  Case in point say you have an interface that is wire-ored and needs a pull up, microcontroller brand XYZ for $3 per part has a set of I/O pins that can be used with no other external hardware required, brand ABC has a $3 part that will require an external transistor and resistor to make it work at a minimum.  Your example of the msp430, say it is about power consumption, part A may only require the user to use one AAA battery and run for months, part B might need two AAA batteries and run for weeks.

The rarest case of all is to actually do the engineering, survey all the vendors, do the power consumption math, the price per unit of your product math, the how big of a rom do we need and what frequency to run the chip at, glue logic, on and on.  Usually someone (boss/customer/senior engineer) takes their years of experience and shoots from the hip (often using one or more of the above) to choose the path (often a good path saving tons of time in schedule and dollars) and the engineering is done once to fine tune the chosen platform.

My personal recommendation is to be flexible.  Most microcontroller brands/families in some form or fashion can be had on an eval board for under $50.  Sparkfun, olimex or direct from the vendor (ti for msp430 or stellaris, etc).  Try one or more of each, get a feel for what is in common and what is different, tools, loaders, how hard to unbrick, etc.  You get two things from this at least, one is that when you are forced down a path from on high or customer you can hit the ground running, second is that when it is your turn to choose the platform you are better educated on what is and isnt out there and can pick the right (loaded word) platform based on the problem to be solved.

Even if you dont or cant go out and spend that kind of money on the hardware, most have tools that you can download (for free), in cases like microchip you can now get the C compiler (used to be Hi-tech) but have to subscribe (give up your email address).  gcc like it or hate it will be in your future, desktop or embedded, get your hands dirty and learn to use it as a cross compiler.  Try llvm too, it will be around for a while and give gcc some serious competition.  Anyway write or find some emulators, mame has many, gdb has some, etc.  I have written one called the thumbulator at github, ARM thumb mode only, similar to a cortex-m3 except I dont support thumb2 (can still learn quite a bit and have programs run on both before you switch over to hardware only).  I whipped up an msp430 emulator but kinda stalled on that.  The instruction set is so small that the bulk of the work is an evening or perhaps a saturday project.  Same goes for the PIC, a long afternoon and you have an instruction set simulator with which to practice embedded.  If nothing else you can just write the programs compile and link to get a feel for how to do that and how big the programs end up being, how to tune the programs to produce tighter code, etc.

As far as C vs assembler, some instruction sets are C friendly and some are not.  Some compilers are medium and some are really bad and only a few are really good (and usually cost a few thousand dollars one time or per year to use).  As with performance anywhere if you want to really push it, a mixture of high level language (lets just say C) and assembler may be required.  So the skill is not writing the whole application in assembler, the skill is determining what code is causing you to not meet timing/performance and then knowing how to solve that either through C, compiler options, choosing the right compiler, or writing assembler.

I recommend that you know assembler for all of the platforms you choose to use, if nothing else readable knowledge of it as with embedded I recommend you disassemble often (while figuring out where your performance problems are).  Many platforms some assembler is required or desired for the boot up code anyway.

If you are wanting to save that 10-20% on price per unit and want to buy the cheaper/slower microcontroller or oscillator, or the 32Kb flash part instead of the 64KB flash part and can cover the development cost with volume of sales, and perhaps a long list of other things you may very well choose to write the whole thing in assembler, fast, low power, low cost, happy customers.

Depending on your background so far, perhaps you shouldnt worry about writing in all assembler and maybe about the electrical engineering aspects of embedded with microcontrollers, reading schematics, knowing what open collector, tri state, push pull, pwm, adc, dac, and a long list of other terms and how to use them.  bit banging i2c, spi, mdio, dallas one wire, etc.  Using a scope as a software debugger.  Even though scopes can highlight things for you today (an extra cost item), you should be able to eyeball i2c and spi and some other protocols without the highlights.

I also recommend that for each of the platforms you play with, get out of someone elses sandbox (the Arduino ide/programming environment for example).  Write the boot code that takes the processor from reset into your main() program, do as much as you can to understand how to load/program the flash to the point that that may involve writing your own loader even though of the shelf ones are there.  It is all about personal education, the more you know and can pull out of your back pocket and use the more control you will have over your career and the more zeros at the end of the number on your paycheck.

Whatever you do, DO NOT, try to learn x86 as your first assembler on a desktop, choose pretty much anything else and cross compile and simulate, ARM, THUMB, MSP430, PIC, AVR, even 6502, 8051.  x86 is a horrible instruction set and as a result has been morphed and shaped in so many ways, microcoded, not microcoded, multi core, on and on.  Keep the x86 to high level languages and bulky operating systems.  Use it for your text editor and compilers and target something else.

Sorry for the long answer...hope it was helpful.

Comment: hmmm, if the question was how do pros choose the size of the flash.  sometimes write some code that resembles the solution, compile and see how big it is.  If an rtos is going to be used, take some samples and size them and add a fudge factor for the code you will add.  A lot of it has to do with personal experience at estimating.  Often you may choose to estimate then double it just in case and your boss may double your estimate so he/she doesnt get in trouble and so on.  And that can help because once implemented you may switch to the smaller part and be a hero with the savings.

Comment: Despite it's length I find this answer very good

Answer (score 3):

The best way to determine flash/RAM requirements for your project is to build a prototype and measure it.

Implement the core algorithms on a PC and calculate the size of object code and RAM usage. This will give you a ballpark figure to work with.

Don't forget to add more to your budget if you're relying on operating system features such as stdio or memory management.

There's no direct way to compare Lines of Code to compiled code size. But, you can compare processor architectures in terms of code density.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to get a "feeling" of what are your requirements, in this case in terms of memory is to get some samples of an MCU, program it and see how many memory is being used. In fact, it will depend on the compiler used. If it's your first time programming a MCU, don't bother too much with specifications. Just select one with lots of memory, lots of peripherals, etc. That way you can learn a lot from just one MCU. When you make your first project with that MCU you will have a better notion of memory you need for further projects.

The most appropriate MCU for a task? How many ADC channels do you need? What about DAC? What is more important in your application: performance or low power?
Is that kind of questions you have to answer when selecting a specific MCU.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a microcontroller that has the set of peripherals that you need.  There will probably be a family of micros that have the same/similar peripheral but different amounts of RAM and Flash.  Start with the chip with the largest RAM/Flash.  Once you have a working prototype, you can drop down to a cheaper micro if your program will fit.

Answer (score 0):

Real professionals do not choose a microcontroller in isolation, they run a project for maximum profit. Depending on the project criteria that might cause a microcontroller to be selected that is a seems to be too expensive, but happens to fit well with the available expertise, tools, libraries, etc. Do not make isolated decisions, keep the big picture in mind, especially the sum (development costs + production costs)!

Most microcontroller manufacturers offer ranges of chips, with flash size one of the parameters that differ among the various chips. A 'safe' choice is to initially select the chip with the largest flash size, so you can scale down if the application fits into a smaller chip. But applications tend to grow to fit all available size (and more).

IME flash size is no longer a big cost factor, even the number of pins is less of a factor, RAM size seems to be the biggest cost driver.